# Apache Pivot cursor image

Tags: custom-cursor, apache-pivot

I'm using Pivot for a desktop application and can't find a way to set an image for the cursor. This exists in AWT (via `java.awt.Toolkit.createCustomCursor`) but the closest in Pivot is `org.apache.pivot.wtk.Mouse.setCursor` which takes an enumerated `org.apache.pivot.wtk.Cursor`, with no option for a custom cursor.

I can't find any way to using an AWT cursor in Pivot, so how can I create a custom cursor in Pivot?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.  There is no provision at the moment for using custom cursors in Pivot.  But, this is a good idea for an enhancement request.  The link for browsing or creating issues for Pivot is here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIVOT